# Why are the Elements of array not printing right?

Tags: c, arrays, function, printing

I'm just starting out with C. I wrote some very basic code for practice, its supposed to read keyboard input into an array, output the length of longest line and then print it.
Theres a function to read the input, I want it to print out each character as it is assigned to the array each time, but it does not work. It prints some strange looking characters.
I did look for "array print garbage" . but didn't find an answer.

```
    int getline(char line[])
    /*
    This function   1) Reads a line of input until a '\n',
                    2) Returns the length of the line and
                    3) Saves the line in the array "line[]"
    */
    {
        int c,i;
        i=0; // The character count
        printf("Enter characters:\n");

        while((c=getchar())!='\n') // Reads input until it hits a '\n'
        {
            line[i]=c;
            i++;
            printf("char %d = %c \n ",i,line[i]);//
```

*Why doesn't this "printf" work right? It prints a strange character at the second placeholder*

```
        }
        printf("you typed %d characters.\n",i); //Outputs the number of characters typed

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: print line[i] before i++

Comment: How do you call getline(x)? What is the declaration of x?

Comment: What if getchar returns `EOF`? You should deal with this also, otherwise it'll be treated as a character, which is wrong.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a ton! @Jens: I'm using Codeblocks, I didn't find handling EOF very useful here, Its ^Z on my machine. When does EOF ever happen from the keyboard? The function is called like this:           
    int longest=0;
    int n;
       while((n=getline(s))!=0) // 'n' becomes length of line entered,char array 's' stores characters in array
    {
        if (n>longest);
        longest=n;
    }

Comment: When you type the EOF character your program crashes because it keeps reading EOFs forever. Run your program with input redirected from /dev/null to see. How is s declared? As a pointer to char or as an array of char? That also makes a big difference.

Comment: @Jens, Thanks for your time man.   I dont understand, I tried entering ^z (EOF), it outputs "char 0= "(just a blank), It counts the ^z character, and then waits for more input. on entering another character and pressing enter ('/n'), it outputs,  "you entered 2 characters."  Sorry, I dont know what " input redirected from /dev/null" means. Thanks anyways.

Comment: ^Z may not be your EOF character. Usually (on Unix at least) it's ^D. EOF usually is -1, and printed as a character it often looks like y-umlaut (ÿ). Your loop never terminates when EOF is hit, and there *will* be an EOF eventually: How do you quit your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing `line[i]` *after* you've incremented `i`. So you're always printing the element after the one you've just set, which is usually garbage.

Put the line

```
i++;
```

at the end of your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks very much Kninnug! Works now. Yay.